# Using PHP doctrine CLI easily in windows

Tags: php, windows, doctrine, cmd

in windows, to use doctrine CLI from any directory i need to use something like

```
php D:\full\path\to\doctrine\bin\doctrine.php --variables here
```

is there anyway i can shorten this so that it becomes something like

```
php doctrine.php --variables here
```

or even

```
doctrine --variables here
```

Comment: Does it work to put the path in windows system paths? Like php is?

Comment: @Iznogood: nope, PATH is only used by windows to find the command.  It's not used to resolve the command's arguments.

Comment: I was thinking of the second option but yeah just reread on that on doctrine's website. Seems you might be out of luck unless you can create some script that binds all that. Sorry I could not help. I use doctrine on linux :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `doskey doctrine=php D:\full\path\to\doctrine\bin\doctrine.php $*`

Then you should be able to do `doctrine --variables here`

If you don't want to type that out every session, you can export it to a file:

```
doskey /macros > macros.txt
```

And import it every session:

```
doskey /macrofile=macros.txt
```

And if that's still too much work, you can add them to the Autorun entry for the CLI:

`reg add "hkcu\software\microsoft\command processor" /v Autorun /t reg_sz /d
"%systemroot%\system32\doskey.exe /macrofile=path\to\your\macros.txt"`

Note that by doing this you are modifying your registry, so use caution.

Comment: Wow doskey is still around! I never think to use the stuff I learned computers on anymore.

Comment: i noticed that this only last for that session, can i make it last forever?

Comment: @jiewmeng: I knew that was coming.  I've updated my answer.  Feel free to re-accept it :)